# Copy constructors - c++

Tags: c++, copy, constructor

Can I write a copy constructor by just passing in a pointer instead of the const reference?  (Would it be ok if I make sure that I am not going to change any values though?)

Like so:

```
SampleClass::SampleClass(SampleClass* p)
{
 //do  the necessary copy functionality
}
```

instead of:

```
SampleClass::SampleClass(const SampleClass& copyObj)
{
//do the necessary copy
}
```

Thanks in advance.

---

Thanks everyone. So, if I write a constructor that takes in a pointer( and thought that's my copy constructor), the compiler would still supply with the default copy constructor in which case my constructor( which i thought was my copy constructor) would not be called and the default copy constructor would be called. Got it.

Answer (score 19):

Yes, you can write a constructor that takes a pointer to the object. However, it cannot be called a copy constructor. The very *definition* of a copy constructor requires you to pass an object of the same class. If you are passing anything else, yes, it's a constructor alright, but not a copy constructor.

Answer (score 4):

You can write a constructor that takes a pointer as an argument.
But the copy constructor is the name we give a specific constructor.
A constructor that takes a reference (preferably const but not required) of the same class as an argument is just named the copy constructor because this is what it effectively does.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the fact that it would not be a copy constructor and the compiler will generate the copy constructor unless you explicitly disable it, there is nothing to gain and much to loose. What is the correct semantics for a constructor out of a null pointer? What does this add to the user of your class? (Hint: nothing, if she wants to construct out of a heap object she can just dereference the pointer and use the regular copy constructor).

Answer (score 1):

No. Copy constructors must take a reference, not pointer, if it's to be useful for passing-by-value, etc.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the copy ctor uses a const reference. While there is nothing stopping you from writing a ctor that takes a pointer, it raises some problems not present when using a reference - e.g., what should/can happen if a null pointer is passed in?

Answer (score 1):

A copy constructor needs a reference because a value parameter would require making a copy, which would invoke the copy constructor, which would make a copy of its parameter, which would invoke the copy constructor, which ...

Answer (score 1):

You can write a constructor like that but its not technically a copy constructor.  For example the STL containers will still use the compiler generated copy constructor (the compiler generates one because you didn't write one).

Answer (score 1):

The copy constructor is implicitly used in two cases:

- When an instance of your class is passed by value to a function.
- When an instance of your class is returned by value from a function.

As others have mentioned, you can write a constructor with the signature described (or with a const pointer), but it would not be used in either of the above cases.

Answer (score -1):

You can write a perfectly valid copy constructor, and still be able to pass a reference that is NULL. You can test for NULL, but only if you do not use constructor initialization lists.

Example:

```
MyClass::MyClass( MyClass const& MyClassCopy )
: somevar( MyClassCopy.somevar ) // <- the init list goes here.
{
   // If MyClassCopy is NULL, the initialization above is doomed!
   // However we can check for NULL in the constructor body but
   // the initialization list must be removed ...
   if (&MyClassCopy == NULL ) throw( std::runtime_error("NULL pointer!"));
   somevar = MyClassCopy.somevar;
}

// I'll now do some very dangerous programming to
// demonstrate one way that a NULL can get through ...
MyClass* P = NULL;
MyClass A( *P ); // Bang, you're dead!
```

As far as I know, there's no way to check for a NULL from inside the initialization list, so if you think you could end up with a situation where a NULL gets through, you have to test for it in the constructor body and do the initializing from there.

Don't forget there's a few gotchas with ::operator=() function to be aware of ...

Comment: You cannot get a null reference without invoking undefined behavior in that code. Testing for NULL after the fact is not useful, as the error is in the other code. In fact, the compiler can optimize away the test `if (&MyClassCopy == NULL)` because it can never happen in a correct program.

Comment: I agree that dereferencing a NULL pointer is an invalid operation, and the test for NULL is best done before the dereference operation. However because the NULL can be assigned during run time, most compilers will allow you to create a NULL reference and there would be no way for the compiler to check for it.  or to optimize a test for NULL out, . You can try it out with g++ and the test works.

Comment: After a moment of reflection, you are correct, you MUST test for null before the dereference operation. The test after the fact is indeed undefined.